# keep a variable for all pages in memory from the url

Tags: variables, globals, session

I downloaded a referrer plugin and it works fine I create my custom link and everything is fine:

https://testsite.com/?r=ty5x

I have a conversion system that tells me how many users have come to my site via the custom link

if you want to see the variable associated with the custom link on the display, just do this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['r'])) {
    echo $_GET['r'];
}
?>
```

where the problem lies, that if the user changes the page and returns to the home page, obviously the url changes, how can I keep the variable r = in memory for the entire browsing session of the user

update $_SESSION

if in functions.php I write the code:

```
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['referrer']=$_GET['r'];

}
```

in front-page.php, write echo:

```
<?php
$ref=$_SESSION['referrer'];
echo $ref;
?>
```

It's perfect, but as soon as I change the page even if I activate the session_start, the variable is not seen

example second page:

```
session_start();

$test = $_SESSION['referrer'];

echo $test;
```

I also tried to enter the $ _SESSION following this example:

```
function test() {
    global $hello;
    $hello = 'hello world';
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'test' );
```

and echo:

```
global $hello;
echo $hello;
```

but no result

i just want a way that once i get the variable from url r =, i can store it while the user goes through all the pages of the site, how can i do this?

Comment: Keep in mind that 3rd party plugin support is offtopic, and you did not share the name of the plugin either

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR: *Use a cookie***

#### Why Not PHP Sessions?

- PHP sessions don't work on most hosts ( e.g. WP Engine which say in their docs they do not support PHP sessions ).
- PHP sessions are incompatible with caching CDNs, caching proxies such as Varnish, and caching plugins.
- They rely on a session ID stored in a cookie, so they can't be used to avoid cookies.
- There are scaling and security concerns, such as spoofed session IDs, storing sessions across load balanced machines, etc

#### Why Not Global Variables?

That's not what global variables are for, or how they work. A global variable lets you change a variables scope so that it can be made everywhere rather than just n that file/functions scope. It has nothing to do with persistence.

To understand why, we have to know that unlike Node applications, PHP programs are loaded from a blank slate every time a page is requested. You can store all the variables you want, but when the page has finished outputting, and the request is over, everything is wiped clean.

This means when you make a request to a WP site, WordPress is loaded from a blank slate, and when the request is finished, it's unloaded. No variables or loaded code persists across requests, it's loaded fresh and brand new every, single, time.

#### So How Do I Persist Something Across a Session?

If you want to store things between requests you have these options:

- store it in a cookie
- store it in the database via user meta/posts/custom tables
- store it externally, e.g. a file, an object cache, remote API
- put it in the HTML then make sure the data is submitted along with the next request to the site ( e.g. a hidden input in a form )

**Because your user isn't logged in, you should use cookies.** If your user *is* logged in then you can store the referral code in user meta via `get_user_meta` and `update_user_meta`.

If your users are landing on a form and you only need the referral code for the form to be filled out, then put it in a hidden input tag and reprint it out on each page.